# how to create security group to allow all ports in java code

Tags: java, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to write java code to create AWS EC2 Security Group inbound traffic to allow for all the ports and source is the same Security Group. I couldn't find the way to do it.
Is allowing "all traffic" in security group is equal to allowing TCP, UDP and ICMP traffic?
Can anyone please help me.

I have tried with the below code. But its throwing error.

Code:- 
AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngressRequest auth_request = new AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngressRequest(); auth_request.setFromPort(-1); auth_request.setToPort(-1); auth_request.setIpProtocol("-1"); auth_request.setSourceSecurityGroupName("default"); auth_request.setGroupId(secGroupId); ec2Client.authorizeSecurityGroupIngress(auth_request);

Exception:-

Error:- 20:35:36.893 [main] DEBUG com.amazonaws.request - Received error response: com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.AmazonEC2Exception: The parameter 'SourceSecurityGroupId' may not be used in combination with 'FromPort' (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterCombination; Request ID: 8e44cc51-5677-411e-95bc-15c968e5a604) Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.AmazonEC2Exception: The parameter 'SourceSecurityGroupId' may not be used in combination with 'FromPort'

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

These are the values you will need to supply:

```
            "SecurityGroupIngress": [
                {
                    "SourceSecurityGroupId" : "sg-abc123",
                    "IpProtocol": "-1",
                    "ToPort": "-1"
                }
            ],
```

The above is in JSON format used for CloudFormation, so you'll have to translate it into Java API calls.

Comment: Is allowing "all traffic" in security group is equal to allowing TCP, UDP and ICMP traffic?

Comment: From the [AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress.html): "IpProtocol: Use -1 to specify all protocols".

Comment: Code:- AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngressRequest auth_request = new AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngressRequest();
  auth_request.setFromPort(-1);
  auth_request.setToPort(-1);
  auth_request.setIpProtocol("-1");
  auth_request.setSourceSecurityGroupName("default");
  auth_request.setGroupId(secGroupId);
ec2Client.authorizeSecurityGroupIngress(auth_request);

Comment: Error:-
20:35:36.893 [main] DEBUG com.amazonaws.request - Received error response: com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.AmazonEC2Exception: The parameter 'SourceSecurityGroupId' may not be used in combination with 'FromPort' (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterCombination; Request ID: 8e44cc51-5677-411e-95bc-15c968e5a604)
Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.AmazonEC2Exception: The parameter 'SourceSecurityGroupId' may not be used in combination with 'FromPort' (Service: AmazonEC2;

Comment: Ah! It's an incoming security group, so there is no need for `FromPort`. Try without it. By the way, you can Edit your question to provide more details rather than trying to squeeze it into a comment.

Comment: The OP wants to restrict port from the specified security group, so allowing all port is not an answer.